# Pandas Aggregate groupby

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks conceptually like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2,3],
    "b": ["a", "a", "c", "a", "d","a"],
    "c": ["2", "3", "4", "2", "3","2"]
})

      a    b    c
  0   1   'a'  '2' 
  1   1   'a'  '3'
  2   1   'c'  '4'
  3   2   'a'  '2'
  4   2   'd'  '3'
  5   3   'a'  '2'
```

For each group in `a` I need to count the unique `(b,c)` values up to here.

So in this example the ouptut should be `[3,4,4]`.

(Because in group 1 there are 3 unique `(b,c)` pairs, and in group 1 and 2 together there are 4 unique `(b,c)` values, and in group 1 and 2 and 3 together there are also only 4 unique `(b,c)` values.

I tried using `expanding` with `groupby` and `nunique` but I couldn't figure out the syntax.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky question. Is this what you are after?

```
result = (
    df.a.drop_duplicates(keep='last')
    .reset_index()['index']
    .apply(lambda x: df.loc[df.index<=x].pipe(lambda x: (x.b+x.c).nunique()))
     )


result
Out[27]: 
0    3
1    4
Name: index, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! this works perfectly (I was kind of hoping there was more of a one-line solution but I guess there isn't).

Answer (score 2):

First find the indices of the unique rows:

```
idx = df[['b','c']].drop_duplicates().index
```

Then find the cumulative sum of the number of rows left in each group:

```
np.cumsum(df.iloc[idx,:].groupby('a').count()['b'])
```

returning

```
a
1    3
2    4
```

Comment: I updated the question a bit to a case your solution doesn't work perfectly. 
Please refine your answer a bit and I will happily accept it.

Comment: @BinyaminEven oshribr got there first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48520734/1011724

Answer (score 2):

I improved Dan's answer.

```
df['t'] = np.cumsum(~df[['b','c']].duplicated())
df.groupby('a')['t'].last()
Out[44]: 
a
1    3
2    4
3    4
Name: t, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `drop_duplicates` after your groupby and get the `shape` of the object :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    "b": ["a", "a", "c", "a", "d"],
    "c": ["2", "3", "4", "2", "3"]
})
result = df.groupby("a").apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().shape[0])
```

If you want to convert the result in list after :

```
result.tolist()
```

The result will be `[3,2]` with your example because you have 3 unique couples for group `a=1` and 2 unique couples for group `a=2`.

If you want the number of unique couple for colums 'b' and 'c' :

```
df[["b", "c"]].drop_duplicates().shape[0]
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I'm after. grouping each group separately is more easy, the whole question is how to aggregate them (assuming I have more than just 2 groups).